# How to enable logInfo in Spark MLlib

Tags: apache-spark, slf4j, apache-spark-mllib

I am running KMeans in Spark MLlib, spark.logging.logInfo (which uses SLF4J) is frequently used inside KMeans and I would like to read the log. However, it is not printed out to the console which I think only prints out logs from log4j. I am wondering how to to enable SLF4J's logInfo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the Spark documentation for [configuring logging](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging)? Spark uses [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) so simply adding `log4j.properties` in the `conf` folder should be enough. You can find a template in their [repository](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/log4j.properties.template).

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought mllib was using a different logging library and log4j won't work for that.